# Element not hiding on load

Tags: jquery, yii

When I load my page the `widget_targets` is visible when it should be hidden on [HumHub](http://humhub.org). When I make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/najzxe7m/12/) it works as it should? No other jquery is called on this view but my script and header stuff but that is why I am using unique identifiers. Why is this?

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <?php if (!$page->isNewRecord) : ?>
        <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', '<strong>Edit</strong> page'); ?></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', '<strong>Create</strong> page'); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget('HActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'page-edit-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        ));
        ?>

        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($page); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'title'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($page, 'title', array('id' => 'item_title', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Page Title'))); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'type'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropdownList($page, 'type', CustomPage::getPageTypes(), array('id' => 'page_type', 'class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '5', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Content Type'))); ?>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group" id="content_field">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'content'); ?><br />
            <div id="conPrefix" style="color:#CC0000">&#x3C;?php</div>
            <?php echo $form->textArea($page, 'content', array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '25', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Content'))); ?>
            <div id="conSuffix" style="color:#CC0000">?&#x3E;</div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="markdown_field">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'markdown'); ?><br />
            <?php echo $form->textArea($page, 'markdown', array('id' => 'markdownForm', 'class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '24', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Content'))); ?>
            <?php $this->widget('application.widgets.MarkdownEditorWidget', array('fieldId' => 'markdownForm')); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="url_field">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'url'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($page, 'url', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'URL'))); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="widget_class">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'widget_class'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropdownList($page, 'widget_class', CustomPage::getWidgetClasses(), array('id' => 'widgetClassField', 'class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '5', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Widget Target'))); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="widget_targets">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'widget_targets'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($page, 'widget_targets', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'widgetTargets')); ?>
            <?php
                $this->widget('application.modules_core.space.widgets.SpacePickerWidget', array(
                    'inputId' => 'widgetTargets',
                    'model' => $page,
                    'maxSpaces' => 50,
                    'attribute' => 'widget_targets'
                ));
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="widget_template">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <?php echo $form->checkBox($page, 'widget_template'); ?> <?php echo $page->getAttributeLabel('widget_template'); ?>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" id="navigation_class">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'navigation_class'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->dropdownList($page, 'navigation_class', CustomPage::getNavigationClasses(), array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '5', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Target'))); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'sort_order'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->textField($page, 'sort_order', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Sort Order'))); ?>
            <p class="help-block"><?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Default sort orders scheme: 100, 200, 300, ...'); ?></p>

        </div>

        <?php
        $faIcons = array("fa-adjust", "fa-adn", "fa-align-center", "fa-align-justify", "fa-align-left", "fa-align-right", "fa-ambulance", "fa-anchor", "fa-android", "fa-angellist", "fa-angle-double-down", "fa-angle-double-left", "fa-angle-double-right", "fa-angle-double-up", "fa-angle-down", "fa-angle-left", "fa-angle-right", "fa-angle-up", "fa-apple", "fa-archive", "fa-area-chart", "fa-arrow-circle-down", "fa-arrow-circle-left", "fa-arrow-circle-o-down", "fa-arrow-circle-o-left", "fa-arrow-circle-o-right", "fa-arrow-circle-o-up", "fa-arrow-circle-right", "fa-arrow-circle-up", "fa-arrow-down", "fa-arrow-left", "fa-arrow-right", "fa-arrow-up", "fa-arrows", "fa-arrows-alt", "fa-arrows-h", "fa-arrows-v", "fa-asterisk", "fa-at", "fa-automobile", "fa-backward", "fa-ban", "fa-bank", "fa-bar-chart", "fa-bar-chart-o", "fa-barcode", "fa-bars", "fa-beer", "fa-behance", "fa-behance-square", "fa-bell", "fa-bell-o", "fa-bell-slash", "fa-bell-slash-o", "fa-bicycle", "fa-binoculars", "fa-birthday-cake", "fa-bitbucket", "fa-bitbucket-square", "fa-bitcoin", "fa-bold", "fa-bolt", "fa-bomb", "fa-book", "fa-bookmark", "fa-bookmark-o", "fa-briefcase", "fa-btc", "fa-bug", "fa-building", "fa-building-o", "fa-bullhorn", "fa-bullseye", "fa-bus", "fa-cab", "fa-calculator", "fa-calendar", "fa-calendar-o", "fa-camera", "fa-camera-retro", "fa-car", "fa-caret-down", "fa-caret-left", "fa-caret-right", "fa-caret-square-o-down", "fa-caret-square-o-left", "fa-caret-square-o-right", "fa-caret-square-o-up", "fa-caret-up", "fa-cc", "fa-cc-amex", "fa-cc-discover", "fa-cc-mastercard", "fa-cc-paypal", "fa-cc-stripe", "fa-cc-visa", "fa-certificate", "fa-chain", "fa-chain-broken", "fa-check", "fa-check-circle", "fa-check-circle-o", "fa-check-square", "fa-check-square-o", "fa-chevron-circle-down", "fa-chevron-circle-left", "fa-chevron-circle-right", "fa-chevron-circle-up", "fa-chevron-down", "fa-chevron-left", "fa-chevron-right", "fa-chevron-up", "fa-child", "fa-circle", "fa-circle-o", "fa-circle-o-notch", "fa-circle-thin", "fa-clipboard", "fa-clock-o", "fa-close", "fa-cloud", "fa-cloud-download", "fa-cloud-upload", "fa-cny", "fa-code", "fa-code-fork", "fa-codepen", "fa-coffee", "fa-cog", "fa-cogs", "fa-columns", "fa-comment", "fa-comment-o", "fa-comments", "fa-comments-o", "fa-compass", "fa-compress", "fa-copy", "fa-copyright", "fa-credit-card", "fa-crop", "fa-crosshairs", "fa-css3", "fa-cube", "fa-cubes", "fa-cut", "fa-cutlery", "fa-dashboard", "fa-database", "fa-dedent", "fa-delicious", "fa-desktop", "fa-deviantart", "fa-digg", "fa-dollar", "fa-dot-circle-o", "fa-download", "fa-dribbble", "fa-dropbox", "fa-drupal", "fa-edit", "fa-eject", "fa-ellipsis-h", "fa-ellipsis-v", "fa-empire", "fa-envelope", "fa-envelope-o", "fa-envelope-square", "fa-eraser", "fa-eur", "fa-euro", "fa-exchange", "fa-exclamation", "fa-exclamation-circle", "fa-exclamation-triangle", "fa-expand", "fa-external-link", "fa-external-link-square", "fa-eye", "fa-eye-slash", "fa-eyedropper", "fa-facebook", "fa-facebook-square", "fa-fast-backward", "fa-fast-forward", "fa-fax", "fa-female", "fa-fighter-jet", "fa-file", "fa-file-archive-o", "fa-file-audio-o", "fa-file-code-o", "fa-file-excel-o", "fa-file-image-o", "fa-file-movie-o", "fa-file-o", "fa-file-pdf-o", "fa-file-photo-o", "fa-file-picture-o", "fa-file-powerpoint-o", "fa-file-sound-o", "fa-file-text", "fa-file-text-o", "fa-file-video-o", "fa-file-word-o", "fa-file-zip-o", "fa-files-o", "fa-film", "fa-filter", "fa-fire", "fa-fire-extinguisher", "fa-flag", "fa-flag-checkered", "fa-flag-o", "fa-flash", "fa-flask", "fa-flickr", "fa-floppy-o", "fa-folder", "fa-folder-o", "fa-folder-open", "fa-folder-open-o", "fa-font", "fa-forward", "fa-foursquare", "fa-frown-o", "fa-futbol-o", "fa-gamepad", "fa-gavel", "fa-gbp", "fa-ge", "fa-gear", "fa-gears", "fa-gift", "fa-git", "fa-git-square", "fa-github", "fa-github-alt", "fa-github-square", "fa-gittip", "fa-glass", "fa-globe", "fa-google", "fa-google-plus", "fa-google-plus-square", "fa-google-wallet", "fa-graduation-cap", "fa-group", "fa-h-square", "fa-hacker-news", "fa-hand-o-down", "fa-hand-o-left", "fa-hand-o-right", "fa-hand-o-up", "fa-hdd-o", "fa-header", "fa-headphones", "fa-heart", "fa-heart-o", "fa-history", "fa-home", "fa-hospital-o", "fa-html5", "fa-ils", "fa-image", "fa-inbox", "fa-indent", "fa-info", "fa-info-circle", "fa-inr", "fa-instagram", "fa-institution", "fa-ioxhost", "fa-italic", "fa-joomla", "fa-jpy", "fa-jsfiddle", "fa-key", "fa-keyboard-o", "fa-krw", "fa-language", "fa-laptop", "fa-lastfm", "fa-lastfm-square", "fa-leaf", "fa-legal", "fa-lemon-o", "fa-level-down", "fa-level-up", "fa-life-bouy", "fa-life-buoy", "fa-life-ring", "fa-life-saver", "fa-lightbulb-o", "fa-line-chart", "fa-link", "fa-linkedin", "fa-linkedin-square", "fa-linux", "fa-list", "fa-list-alt", "fa-list-ol", "fa-list-ul", "fa-location-arrow", "fa-lock", "fa-long-arrow-down", "fa-long-arrow-left", "fa-long-arrow-right", "fa-long-arrow-up", "fa-magic", "fa-magnet", "fa-mail-forward", "fa-mail-reply", "fa-mail-reply-all", "fa-male", "fa-map-marker", "fa-maxcdn", "fa-meanpath", "fa-medkit", "fa-meh-o", "fa-microphone", "fa-microphone-slash", "fa-minus", "fa-minus-circle", "fa-minus-square", "fa-minus-square-o", "fa-mobile", "fa-mobile-phone", "fa-money", "fa-moon-o", "fa-mortar-board", "fa-music", "fa-navicon", "fa-newspaper-o", "fa-openid", "fa-outdent", "fa-pagelines", "fa-paint-brush", "fa-paper-plane", "fa-paper-plane-o", "fa-paperclip", "fa-paragraph", "fa-paste", "fa-pause", "fa-paw", "fa-paypal", "fa-pencil", "fa-pencil-square", "fa-pencil-square-o", "fa-phone", "fa-phone-square", "fa-photo", "fa-picture-o", "fa-pie-chart", "fa-pied-piper", "fa-pied-piper-alt", "fa-pinterest", "fa-pinterest-square", "fa-plane", "fa-play", "fa-play-circle", "fa-play-circle-o", "fa-plug", "fa-plus", "fa-plus-circle", "fa-plus-square", "fa-plus-square-o", "fa-power-off", "fa-print", "fa-puzzle-piece", "fa-qq", "fa-qrcode", "fa-question", "fa-question-circle", "fa-quote-left", "fa-quote-right", "fa-ra", "fa-random", "fa-rebel", "fa-recycle", "fa-reddit", "fa-reddit-square", "fa-refresh", "fa-remove", "fa-renren", "fa-reorder", "fa-repeat", "fa-reply", "fa-reply-all", "fa-retweet", "fa-rmb", "fa-road", "fa-rocket", "fa-rotate-left", "fa-rotate-right", "fa-rouble", "fa-rss", "fa-rss-square", "fa-rub", "fa-ruble", "fa-rupee", "fa-save", "fa-scissors", "fa-search", "fa-search-minus", "fa-search-plus", "fa-send", "fa-send-o", "fa-share", "fa-share-alt", "fa-share-alt-square", "fa-share-square", "fa-share-square-o", "fa-shekel", "fa-sheqel", "fa-shield", "fa-shopping-cart", "fa-sign-in", "fa-sign-out", "fa-signal", "fa-sitemap", "fa-skype", "fa-slack", "fa-sliders", "fa-slideshare", "fa-smile-o", "fa-soccer-ball-o", "fa-sort", "fa-sort-alpha-asc", "fa-sort-alpha-desc", "fa-sort-amount-asc", "fa-sort-amount-desc", "fa-sort-asc", "fa-sort-desc", "fa-sort-down", "fa-sort-numeric-asc", "fa-sort-numeric-desc", "fa-sort-up", "fa-soundcloud", "fa-space-shuttle", "fa-spinner", "fa-spoon", "fa-spotify", "fa-square", "fa-square-o", "fa-stack-exchange", "fa-stack-overflow", "fa-star", "fa-star-half", "fa-star-half-empty", "fa-star-half-full", "fa-star-half-o", "fa-star-o", "fa-steam", "fa-steam-square", "fa-step-backward", "fa-step-forward", "fa-stethoscope", "fa-stop", "fa-strikethrough", "fa-stumbleupon", "fa-stumbleupon-circle", "fa-subscript", "fa-suitcase", "fa-sun-o", "fa-superscript", "fa-support", "fa-table", "fa-tablet", "fa-tachometer", "fa-tag", "fa-tags", "fa-tasks", "fa-taxi", "fa-tencent-weibo", "fa-terminal", "fa-text-height", "fa-text-width", "fa-th", "fa-th-large", "fa-th-list", "fa-thumb-tack", "fa-thumbs-down", "fa-thumbs-o-down", "fa-thumbs-o-up", "fa-thumbs-up", "fa-ticket", "fa-times", "fa-times-circle", "fa-times-circle-o", "fa-tint", "fa-toggle-down", "fa-toggle-left", "fa-toggle-off", "fa-toggle-on", "fa-toggle-right", "fa-toggle-up", "fa-trash", "fa-trash-o", "fa-tree", "fa-trello", "fa-trophy", "fa-truck", "fa-try", "fa-tty", "fa-tumblr", "fa-tumblr-square", "fa-turkish-lira", "fa-twitch", "fa-twitter", "fa-twitter-square", "fa-umbrella", "fa-underline", "fa-undo", "fa-university", "fa-unlink", "fa-unlock", "fa-unlock-alt", "fa-unsorted", "fa-upload", "fa-usd", "fa-user", "fa-user-md", "fa-users", "fa-video-camera", "fa-vimeo-square", "fa-vine", "fa-vk", "fa-volume-down", "fa-volume-off", "fa-volume-up", "fa-warning", "fa-wechat", "fa-weibo", "fa-weixin", "fa-wheelchair", "fa-wifi", "fa-windows", "fa-won", "fa-wordpress", "fa-wrench", "fa-xing", "fa-xing-square", "fa-yahoo", "fa-yelp", "fa-yen", "fa-youtube", "fa-youtube-play");
        ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($page, 'icon'); ?>

            <select class='selectpicker form-control' name="CustomPage[icon]">
                <?php 
                    $first = true; 
                    $second = true;
                    foreach ($faIcons as $icon):
                ?>
                    <?php if ($first): ?>
                        <option data-content="None" value="none" <?php if ($page->icon == 'none'): ?>selected='selected'<?php endif; ?>>None</option> 
                    <?php $first = false; ?>
                    <?php elseif (!$first && $second): ?>
                        <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-fw'></i>" value="fa-fw" <?php if ($page->icon == 'fa-fw'): ?>selected='selected'<?php endif; ?>>Blank</option>
                    <?php $second = false; ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <option data-content="<i class='fa <?php echo $icon; ?>'></i>" value="<?php echo $icon; ?>" <?php if ($page->icon == $icon): ?>selected='selected'<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $icon; ?></option>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <?php echo $form->checkBox($page, 'admin_only'); ?> <?php echo $page->getAttributeLabel('admin_only'); ?>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <?php echo $form->checkBox($page, 'visibility'); ?> <?php echo $page->getAttributeLabel('visibility'); ?>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>        

        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Save'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>

        <?php
        if (!$page->isNewRecord) {
            echo CHtml::link(Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Delete'), $this->createUrl('//custom_pages/admin/delete', array('id' => $page->id)), array('class' => 'btn btn-danger'));
        }
        ?>

        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div>
</div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var t = $("#page_type").val();
            var telm = $("#page_type");
            $("#widget_class").hide();
            $("#widget_template").hide();
            $("#widget_targets").hide();
            if (t == '1' || t == '3') {
                $("#content_field").hide();
                $("#url_field").show();
                $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Page Title'); ?>');
                $("#conPrefix").hide();
                $("#conSuffix").hide();
                $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); });
                $("#navigation_class").show();
            } else  if (t == '2' || t == '4') {
                $("#navigation_class").show();
                $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); });
                $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Page Title'); ?>');
                $("#content_field").show();
                $("#url_field").hide();
                $("#conPrefix").hide();
                $("#conSuffix").hide();   
            } else  if (t == '5') {
                $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Page Title'); ?>');
                $("#content_field").show();
                $("#url_field").hide();
                $("#navigation_class").show();
                $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); });
                $("#conPrefix").show();
                $("#conSuffix").show();
            } else if (t == '6') {
                $("#widget_class").show(function(){ 
                    $('#widgetClassField').on('change', function(){ 
                        if ($('#widgetClassField').val() == 'SpaceSidebarWidget') {
                            $('#widget_targets').show();
                        } else {
                            $('#widget_targets').hide(); 
                        }
                    }); $(document).trigger('change'); 
                });
                $("#widget_template").show();
                $("#content_field").show();
                $("#url_field").hide();
                $("#navigation_class").hide();
                $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Widget Name'); ?>');
                $("#conPrefix").show();
                $("#conSuffix").show();
            }
            if (t == '4') {
                $("#content_field").hide();
                $("#markdown_field").show();
            } else {
                $("#markdown_field").hide();
            }
            if (t != '6') {
                $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); });
            }

            telm.on('change', function() {
                var t = $("#page_type").val();
                if (t == '1' || t == '3') {
                    $("#content_field").hide();
                    $("#url_field").show();
                    $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Page Title'); ?>');
                    $("#conPrefix").hide();
                    $("#conSuffix").hide();
                    $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); }); 
                    $("#navigation_class").show();
                    $(document).trigger('change');
                } else if (t == '2' || t == '4') {
                    $("#navigation_class").show();
                    $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); });
                    $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Page Title'); ?>');
                    $("#content_field").show();
                    $("#url_field").hide();
                    $("#conPrefix").hide();
                    $("#conSuffix").hide();   
                    $(document).trigger('change');
                } else if (t == '5') {
                    $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Page Title'); ?>');
                    $("#content_field").show();
                    $("#url_field").hide();
                    $("#navigation_class").show();
                    $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); });
                    $("#conPrefix").show();
                    $("#conSuffix").show();
                    $(document).trigger('change');
                } else if (t == '6') {
                    $("#widget_class").show(function(){ 
                    $('#widgetClassField').on('change', function(){ 
                            if ($('#widgetClassField').val() == 'SpaceSidebarWidget') {
                                $('#widget_targets').show();
                            } else {
                                $('#widget_targets').hide(); 
                            }
                        }); $(document).trigger('change'); 
                    });
                    $("#widget_template").show();
                    $("#content_field").show();
                    $("#url_field").hide();
                    $("#navigation_class").hide();
                    $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', '<?php echo Yii::t('CustomPages.views_admin_edit', 'Widget Name'); ?>');
                    $("#conPrefix").show();
                    $("#conSuffix").show();
                    $(document).trigger('change');
                }
                if (t == '4') {
                    $("#content_field").hide();
                    $("#markdown_field").show();
                    $(document).trigger('change');
                } else {
                    $("#markdown_field").hide();
                    $(document).trigger('change');
                }
                if (t != '6') {
                    $("#widget_class").hide(function(){ $('#page_type').on('change', function(){ $('#widget_targets').hide(); $('#widget_template').hide(); }); });
                }

            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: In the [target page](https://www.humhub.org/en/overview) there are no elements with id `widget_targets`

Comment: Sorry, that is the software using the Yii Framework that I am using.

Comment: I added full bugged page. I'm sure my approach to hiding/showing these elements is not the best or most practical which is causing the conflicts.

Comment: if you run `$("#widget_targets").hide();` in the console whether it is getting hidden....

Comment: also in your console try `$("[id=widget_targets]").length`

Comment: It hides just fine when selecting a page type (the selection field set to Link by default) and appear when it should be selecting Widget and then selecting last option which would be "SpaceSidebarWidget". And of course hides just fine when I run the command via console. It's just not initally hiding on HumHub, but does on the fiddle. It's weird. I tried `$(document).load()` instead of `.ready()` to no avail as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76951/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-wasasquatch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original reported issue was because of server side caching of components, but the given code can be simplified using .toggle() as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $ptype = $("#page_type"),
        $wcf = $('#widgetClassField');

    $wcf.on('change', function () {
        $('#widget_targets').toggle($(this).val() == 'SpaceSidebarWidget' && $ptype.val() == 6);
    });

    $ptype.on('change', function () {
        var t = telm.val();

        $("#content_field").toggle(t == 2 || t == 5 || t == 6);
        $("#conPrefix, #conSuffix").toggle(t == 5 || t == 6);
        $("#url_field").toggle(t == 1 || t == 3);
        $("#navigation_class").toggle(t != 6);
        $("#markdown_field").toggle(t == 4);
        $("#widget_class, #widget_template").toggle(t == 6);
        $('#widget_targets').toggle($wcf.val() == 'SpaceSidebarWidget' && t == 6);

        $("#widget_template").toggle(t == 6);

        if (t == 6) {
            $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', 'Widget Name');
        } else {
            $("#item_title").attr('placeholder', 'Oage Title');
        }
    }).change();
});
```